# How to display images in web page using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I already know how to save images in mongodb using angularjs and java to save it in my mongodb,

I need to get the saved image from mongodb and display it in an html page using AngularJS.

This is my controller for getting image

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getById(@PathParam("id") String id) throws IOException
{
    Response response = null;
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB mongoDB = mongoClient.getDB("sampleDB");
    DBCollection collection = mongoDB.getCollection("filestore");
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    ObjectId oid = new ObjectId(id);
    query.put("_id", oid);
    GridFS fileStore = new GridFS(mongoDB, "filestore");
    GridFSDBFile gridFile = fileStore.findOne(query);
    InputStream in = gridFile.getInputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int data = in.read();
    while (data >= 0)
    {
    out.write((char) data);
    data = in.read();
    }
    out.flush();
    ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok(out.toByteArray());
    builder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=");
    response = builder.build();
    return response;
}
```

This is my angularjs for getting image

```
var userImagePromise = $http.get("../api/s3/" + $scope.user.profileImage[0].id);
userImagePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.imageData = data;
});
userImagePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
});
```

This is my html for displaying image

```
<img id="userProfileImg" height="150px" width="150px" ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{imageData}}">
```

if I simply put the link to browser i got this output in octect-stream

�PNG .....

How to display image in html?Any error in my code wise?

[Image for getting output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFvd9.png)

Comment: what do u mean by this--->data:image/png;base64,{{imageData}}?? have u tried with ng-src={{imageData}}??

Comment: @Sa E Chowdary yes i tried but it wont working I stringify that imageData its look like ?PNG and some  symbols in big data

Comment: can u post what your getting in $scope.imageData.

Comment: @Sa E Chowdary I acnt able to post it octect-stream content type �PNG .and some symbols cant able to copy that data�PNG

Comment: @Sa E Chowdary  i updated the image pls click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your base64 code is not converting images properly, so check my code it may help you.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;




BufferedImage buffimage = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(buffimage, "png", baos);
String img = Base64.encode(baos.toByteArray());
```

send  this img variable to your angularjs code.